# Can Android accept writing NFC tags (emulate empty NFC tag)?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, nfc

Can Android device emulate an empty NFC tag that accepts writing to it? I see that Android can read/write NFC tags, it can also emulate an NFC tag (with it you can emit data), but I would like to try accepting writing NFC tags, is it possible?

Since iOS can only write NFC tag, not emulate one it would be nice to emulate an empty NFC tag so that an iPhone device can "write" to it, meaning transfer data. I already tried emulating NFC tags on android and reading them on an iPhone and it works correctly. If only there would be a way to do the reverse somehow.